# Highlight dates closer than 3 months away

Tags: office-scripts, excel-online

I have a simple spreadsheet listing certificates and expiry dates. Before we moved this to sharepoint online we had a macro than on opening the spreadsheet would check dates in a range of cells and highlight those within three months. It was intended to highlight anything up for renewal before it expired.

I appreciate macros are not an option in Excel online. Can this (or something very similar) be achieved in Office Scripting?

Comment: Do some research on conditional formatting, that should solve your issue.

Comment: I have looked at conditional formatting online but I am very limited in the criteria I can format by. There appears to be no facility to apply formatting based on a date three months ahead, only one month. Using a local installation this is possible as you are offered more options for the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to create an Office Script that highlights cells with a date that is within three months of the present.

Something Like:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  // highlight all days between today and the next number of days out
  // Number of days to look ahead
  const daysOut = 90;

  // Excel by default stores dates as the number of days after January 1, 1900
  const dayMin = currentDaysSince1900();
  const dayMax = dayMin + daysOut; 

  // Need to target the column to look at and how far down the column
  const columnToLookAt = "A";
  const rowStart = 1;
  const rowEnd = 4;

  const rangeAddress = `${columnToLookAt}${rowStart}:${columnToLookAt}${rowEnd}`;

  const sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // get range column
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A3");
  const values = range.getValues();

  // iterate through the rows of values
  for (let i =0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
    const value = values[i][0];
    console.log(value);
    if (typeof value === "number") {
      // only look at numbers
      if (value >= dayMin && value <=dayMax ) {

        // highlight
        const rangeAddress = `${columnToLookAt}${rowStart +i}`;
        const range = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
        range.getFormat().getFill().setColor("yellow");
      }
    } 
  }

  
}

/**
 * Current Days since Jan 1 1900
 * Equivalent to number of current excel day
 */
function currentDaysSince1900() {

  // method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970
  const nowMilliseconds = Date.now();

  const millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
  const nowDays = Math.floor(nowMilliseconds / millisecondsPerDay);
  const daysBetween1900And1970 = 25567;

  const elapsed = nowDays + daysBetween1900And1970 +2; // add two to include both jan 1s

  return elapsed;
}
```

In terms of triggering the script:

- Office Script does not currently support running a script on opening a workbook.
- You can manually trigger the script whenever you like.
- You can also create a Microsoft Power Automate flow to run the script every day to keep the workbook updated.

More Office Script resources:

- [Official Microsoft Office Script Date Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples#dates)
- [Official Microsoft Office Script Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples)
- [wandyezj office script examples](https://github.com/wandyezj/office-script)